# Efecto de scroll en una columna

Tags: bootstrap, scroll

Estoy programando una página web con Bootstrap y en una de las páginas tengo una estructura de dos columnas. En la derecha tengo una imagen o varias y a la izquierda un texto que es la descripción de la imagen. Lo que quiero conseguir es que al hacer scroll hacia abajo para ver la imagen completa o todas las imágenes, el texto me acompañe.

Probé a utilizar position: fixed en el texto o el atributo affix pero no funciona ya que el texto me acompaña pero no se ve entero porque se mete por debajo de la imagen.

La página la podéis encontrar aquí:

http://clients.sabrinacouto.com/kiige/res_publica.html

Si es necesario copio el css o el código html.

Alguna idea de porqué puede pasar esto o si hay alguna otra forma de solucionarlo?

Código:

```
<section class="row2 text-center col-md-12 center-block text-center">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <div class="projectext">
      <p class="">Res Publica valimiskampaania graafilise stiili kujundus välireklaamidele ja trükistele.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="images/Res Publica valimiskampaania kujundus.jpg" class="img-responsive pull-left" alt="web design app image";>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
.projectext{

position: fixed;
overflow:hidden;
```

}

[image: Ejemplo]

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, es mejor que separes las dos preguntas.

Comment: @AlbertoMier Vale, ya lo he editado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elimina el `position: fixed;` y ya no se te pondrá encima.

Cuándo utilizas `fixed` no tiene en cuenta la posición de nada, sino que se coloca por defecto en el 0,0 de su espacio disponible.

Si quieres utilizar `fixed` para que el texto te siga con la página mantenlo así pero añade un `margin-left` en todas tus imágenes (añádelo en una clase css para las imágenes).

En concreto podrías:

```
.projectext{
    position: fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: vale, usando el margin-left funciona pero no hay una manera de hacerlo responsive? porque a medida que la pantalla es más pequeña pasa lo mismo de antes, el texto se mete por debajo de la imagen.Ahora estoy arreglándolo con las mediaqueries pero nose si habrá otra manera más directa o "correcta" de hacerlo. Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Podrías darle un valor `width` mucho más pequeño al texto de manera que te ocupe mucho menos espacio por la izquierda y darle ese mismo valor `width` pero a `margin-left` a las imágenes sumándole 5-10px

Comment: vale, ahora sí que funciona. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Perfecto @Sabrina! Me alegro que te haya ido bien. Si te ha ayudado por favor acepta la respuesta (http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: hecho! gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando trabajas con boostrap se supone que las imagenes deben ser responsive para que se adapte a la resolucion del dispositivo

[Bootstrap Images](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-images.php)

como observaras en el articulo la definicion del `class="img-responsive"`

```
<img src="kites.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Flying Kites">
```

esto hara que la imagen se adapte.

Respecto al texto, evalua lo comentado aqui

[More HTML & CSS: Images with Bootstrap](http://code.makery.ch/library/more-html-css/image-bootstrap/)

veras que puede aplicar el estilo `class="pull-right"` para adaptarlo a la imagen

```
<img src="..." alt="..." class="pull-right">
```

Comment: la class de img responsive ya la tiene la imagen. En cuanto al texto, probé a añadirle lo de pull-right pero apenas se mueve. El texto sigue metiéndose por debajo de la imagen (una parte de él). He editado mi pregunta para copiar el código HTML, CSS y el ejemplo de como queda con position:fixed